# Enabling background mode stopped my console logs for simulator , only start seldom time in XCode

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7, background-process

Enabling background mode stopped my console logs for simulator , only start seldom time in Xcode.

Have anyone faced this issue.

I don't want to reset content settings all the time , do anyone facing this and have fixed.

Comment: Please give more context.  What do you mean by this?  syslog continues to log to ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[UDID]/system.log, and in the simulator, backgrounded processes are not suspended like they are on device, so you should still see logging.

Comment: I always see the Console area (lldb) | blank and have to restart continuously to get once linked some how.

Comment: Please note that I have to turn of the background mode in the Build Settings  then only that work fine. Else its like the debugger is never attached what i see when i put the breakpoint at didfinishlaunchwithoptions function.